problemas para cargar Anaconda desde un link a un EC2 de aws
he iniciado un curso de pyspark y dentro de los pasos inciales me piden instalar anaconda a una maquina virtual EC2 de aws, pero al ejecurar wget o curl no me descarga el archivo e incluso indica qe fue removido. Consulte la documentacion de Anaconda y me indica que lo solicte por el marketplace de aws. ¿han tenido el mismo problema para instalar anaconda? de antemano les agradezco mucho.
